# counting program with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a homework:

> import 3 numbers `n`,`m`,`k`. Count all numbers between `m` and `n` divisible by `k`

And this is my code, can anyone tell me what is wrong with that?

```js
var n = parseInt(prompt("enter N"));
var m = parseInt(prompt("enter M"));
var k = parseInt(prompt("enter K"));

for (var i=0; n<=i<=m; i++)
{
    if (i % k == 0)
    {
        document.write( i + '&nbsp;');
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.write` is very very rarely used in modern javascript. You would do best to forget that it even exists

Comment: I think that you have to change for loop because n is   <= of i only when is negative or 0.

Comment: *what wrong with that* – please describe how have you figured something's wrong with your solution and what exactly is wrong. Questions demanding help with debugging have to contain the expected and the actual behaviours (as well as the shortest code which reproduces the issue – you have that already)

Comment: You list the numbers that fulfill the predicate instead of counting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop has to be rewritten as such:

```js
var n = parseInt(prompt("enter N"));
var m = parseInt(prompt("enter M"));
var k = parseInt(prompt("enter K"));
for(var i=n; i<=m; i++){
 if (i % k == 0){
  document.write( i + '&nbsp;');
 }
}
```